# Como faço para criar um menu de instalação com check box?

Tags: c#, checkbox, menu

Estou criando um menu de instalação com **CheckBox**, nesse menu irá ter softwares para instalação em cada CheckBox, após selecionar os CheckBox, terá um botão que irá executar todos os **checkbox** selecionados. 
Cada CheckBox irá executar a instalação de um software, porém todos os selecionados executam de uma vez só, como faço para que ele faça uma instalação por vez?
Meu código:

```
if (CheckBox2.Checked)
    Process.Start(@"\Index\Menu de Instalacao\Softwares\Utilitarios\PROGRAMA1.EXE");

if (CheckBox3.Checked)
    Process.Start(@"\Index\Menu de Instalacao\Softwares\");
```

Comment: Reformulada a pergunta e com mais detalhes. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seguinte método recebe o caminho de um executável, chama o executável e espera até que ele encerre.

```
public void AguardarAteEncerrar(string caminhoExecutavel)
{
    var processo = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
        {
            FileName = caminhoExecutavel
        }
    };

    processo.Start();
    processo.WaitForExit();
}
```

Você usaria assim:

```
if (CheckBox2.Checked)
    AguardarAteEncerrar(@"\Index\Menu de Instalacao\Softwares\Utilitarios\PROGRAMA1.EXE");
```

Tenha em mente que isso vai segurar a thread, então evite usá-lo na mesma thread na GUI. Sugiro que use um [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) neste caso.

Comment: Era tudo que eu precisava, muito agradecido Gabriel. Funcionou perfeitamente.